# where and how do i get gcc g++ 7.3.0

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, sfml, dev-c++

I would like to use SFML but at first place i need to get the same version of SFML and dev c++ compiler. It was easy to get the SFML 7.3.0 version, but i can't find the 7.3.0 version of compiler, even the MinGW installation manager doesn't have it, but i need it. I've tried searching the internet, but i found nothing that could possibly help me. The only way for me to use SFML, is using 4.9.2 version of compiler and SFML for now, but it's old and have a lot of bugs/oversights. So if u use SFML 7.3.0 or know how to get and use it, pls tell me how to.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand how versioning works. SFML is totally separate and distinct from the compiler. You don't need to match compiler and library versions.

Comment: This sounds very misinformed, but I'm not familiar enough with SFML to say it definiteively.

Comment: Besides that, [SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org) is only up to version 2.5.1. And there never was a 7.2 release of GCC.

Comment: In short: Get the latest compiler you can get (GCC is up to 11.2) and the latest SFML (2.5.1) you can get. Install both. Use the compiler to build your application with SFML.

Comment: I'll always throw out that dev-c++ is hot garbage and shouldn't be bothered with. Too many good alternatives to bother trying to find the one fork that isn't horrible.

Comment: You can, and have to configure dev-c++ to use a newer compiler version, as the outdated it's delivered with.

Comment: [Link to modern port of Dev C++](https://github.com/Embarcadero/Dev-Cpp/releases). You can get it with GCC9.2 or without and install your own toolchain. Your call, but I recommend the latter and [the MSYS2 toolchain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30071634/4581301). You can use MSYS2's package manager to download and set up SFML libraries tuned to match the rest of the tools. MSYS2 is pretty much one-stop shopping and saves a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't follow your statement that you need the MinGW GCC 7.3.0 compiler to build SFML 7.3.0.

When looking at SFML (https://www.sfml-dev.org/download.php) the latest version seems to be 2.5.1.

That version builds perfectly well with more recent versions of MinGW/MinGW-w64.In fact even the latest GCC 11.2.0 can build it - I used the 64-bit standalone build from https://winlibs.com/ to try this.

GCC 7.3.0 is several years old. There is usually no reason to use very old GCC versions. Instead you can tell GCC to use an older standard of the C language with the `-std=` flag (e.g. `-std=c89`).

Comment: Actually, in the downloads section of SFML, you find that the downloads have a GCC version associated, and also the writing "The compiler versions have to match 100%!".

Comment: I totally agree you shouldn't mix compiler versions, but that's no excuse for using such an extremely old compiler version. Personally I build SFML and its dependencies with the latest MinGW-w64/GCC without issues. My build recipe can be found here: https://github.com/brechtsanders/winlibs_recipes/blob/main/recipes/sfml.winlib